# Problem wiimote LED- and vibration-feedback

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In fuerte the wii's LED and vibration work perfectly, but if I test it on electric, it doesn't work. Any idea what the problem could be and how to fix it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49129/problem-wiimote-led--and-vibration-feedback/) by [E_Geerts](https://answers.ros.org/users/3670/e_geerts/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-11-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2012-11-26**:
Do you possibly mean that it worked in Electric, but not in Fuerte? If you compare the [electric message api](http://ros.org/doc/electric/api/wiimote/html/index-msg.html) and the [fuerte message api](http://ros.org/doc/fuerte/api/wiimote/html/index-msg.html).....

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2012-11-26**:
.... you'll notice the `LEDControl` and `RumbleControl` message definitions disappeared in Fuerte.  I'm not sure why, but they did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

jarvis is correct, the API changed from Electric to Fuerte.

In Electric, the WiiMote had its own API.  In Fuerte, this was changed over to use the common API with the PS3 joy node:
http://ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/JoyFeedbackArray.html

For an example of how to use the common API, see here:
http://ros.org/doc/fuerte/api/wiimote/html/feedbackTester_8py_source.html

Just note that the WiiMote only has on/off for each element, so values >= 0.5 are 'ON' while values < 0.5 are 'OFF'.  That script is essentially a unit test to ensure that "analog" inputs are rounded to the correct binary outputs.

---

Originally posted by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) with karma: 4541 on 2012-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0